# What is the Process Game on iOS?

Tags: ios, battery

My iPhone was extremely hot this morning after I checked twitter and watched a few TikTok videos. The battery drains extremely fast. Then I checked the Activity Monitor on Mac and it seems the process Game caused it. What is the process Game?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any games that run in widgets?

Comment: @fsb No, I only have a Apple Music widget and two Webull(brokerage app) widgets.